# Select ' ' from TableA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What exactly does

```
select '' from TableA
```

do?

When I run it on a given table I get back a record for all rows in the table that are obviously blank with the header of '(No column name)' because no alias was used.
I have seen this query used as a subquery in 'not exists' statements.

At what times would this query be useful and is it a good practice to query this way?

For instance when I first saw it I thought it would return one blank row but in fact it returns all rows in the table and they are blank.

I've looked around and haven't found an answer for this.
Thank you

Comment: it can be useful in `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, when it just checks the existence of a row with some conditions

Comment: @Lamak thank you, I tried checking the query execution plan for it too to look behind the scenes but do not have the right permissions.

Comment: It is just doing the check whether there is any records return, same as `select 1 from table`, and using this with `exists` may boost your performance because if it finds any result then move to the next part, you do not really need to care about it is returning all rows with blank value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking whether something exists in a table, it is common to select an arbitrary value rather than an actual column, because it has an affect on the execution plan (if you select a real column, the execution plan takes that column into account and it can take a little longer, even though you don't use the column).

Most commonly, I have seen `1`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn > 10)
```

If you just care whether there is *any* row, you can short circuit the query rather than getting all rows... although I suspect the `EXISTS` statement would stop as soon as any row was found anyway.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 '' FROM TableA)
```

Comment: thanks @Fenton  I tried checking the query execution plan for it too to look behind the scenes but do not have the right permissions

Answer (score 0):

You would use this syntax if you want to add a static value as part of your query for any reason

E.g.

```
SELECT 
    'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM '+name 
from sys.objects 
where type = 'U'
```

This will create automatically create queries for all tables you have in your database